# Function that Returns the Length of an Array of Specific Characters (Javascript)

Tags: javascript

I need help writing a function that returns the length of an array of characters that match "a" || "e" || "i" || "o" || "u".

```js
function getCount(str) {
  let count = str.split("").filter((ch) => {
    return ch === "a" || "e" || "i" || "o" || "u"
  }).length;
  return count;
}

console.log(getCount("abracadabra"));
//"a" || "e" || "i" || "o" || "u"
```

For some reason, it is returning 11, instead of the correct value of 5.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry but you're not doing the comparison right.

```js
function getCount(str) {
  let count = str.split("").filter((ch) => {
    return ch === "a" ||  ch ===  "e" ||  ch === "i" || ch ===  "o" || ch ===  "u"
  }).length;
  return count;
}

console.log(getCount("abracadabra"));
```

Comment: It's unfortunate that there is not a way to check a single element against multiple because this checks the same over 5 values. Anyways, thanks @Jonathan Akwetey Okine!

Comment: what are you hoping to achieve? Maybe you should update your question accordingly I thought you wanted to check the characters against the values you provided.

Comment: this achieves exactly what I want, sorry for the misunderstanding. I was just looking for the shortest way to check a single value against multiple values. I'm blaming JS lol.